# Not able to retrieve the Objects from RestController of Spring boot to angular 6 service

Tags: java, angular, spring, spring-boot

I have the below code snippet

My Rest controller:

```
    @RestController
    @RequestMapping("/hello")
    public class HelloController{
      @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, path="getUser")
      public UserDetails getUserDetails(){
        return userdetails;
      }
    }
```

Model Object

```
    Public Class UserDetails{
       public String name;
       public String role;
    //getters and setters go here

    }
```

angular code
appcomponent.ts

```
    baseUrl = "/hello"
    userdetails: UserDetails;

    this.http.get(`${this.baseUrl}`).subscribe((data : any) => 
         this.userdetails = data);
    console.log(this.userdetails);
```

UserDetails.ts

```
    export class UserDetails {
        name: string;
        role: number;
    }
```

the call is going to controller (I checked in debug mode), but not able to get the response to angular (userdetails is coming as undefined)

Comment: did you enable the CORS?

Comment: Yes, I have enabled

Comment: 1.try to call rest service from postman and replace same url at `${this.baseUrl}`.see whether you will get or not?
2.if you still get undefined, use promises.

Comment: why is that in your java code you have sting role, and in angular number?. from what i know these datatypes should also be the same,

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you use the same types for variables as in the service:

```
UserDetails.ts
    export class UserDetails {
        name: string;
        role: string;
    }
```

Also try to use generics in your call to ensure type compatibility:

```
this.http.get<UserDetails>(`${this.baseUrl}`).subscribe((data : UserDetails)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should have the type specified explicitly in the get method and you can subscrie to the data, like below and also use a subscribe in the below way. Have your UserDetails file with same data type specified in java

```
this.http.get<UserDetails>(this.baseURL).subscribe(
  data => {
    this.userDetails= data;
    console.log(this.userDetails.name);
    console.log(this.userDetails.role);
  }
);
```

Comment: Still not getting

Comment: Have you modified your UserDetails file? and have you added @CrossOrigin annotation in your spring boot method in controller

Answer (score 0):

I have modified my UserDetails file but Sorry my bad, i forgot to map in the service call
this.http.get(`${this.baseUrl}`).map((res: UserDetails) => res)